# How to insert all text values at first row only in SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created textboxes dynamically using the below code

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.Name = ("txt" + (i + 1)).ToString();
txt.Location = new Point(1160, 148 + (850 * i));

Size txtsize = new Size(260, 50);
txt.Size = txtsize;
txt.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
txt.Multiline = true;
txt.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold);

this.Controls.Add(txt);
```

When I inserted values into database

```
if (txt.Name == "txt1")
{
    string str = "insert into sample1 (txt1) values ('" + txt.Text+"')";

    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
         conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@txt1", txt.Text.Trim()));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
}
.......
```

I am getting the output like

```
txt1   txt2   txt3
-------------------
10     NULL   NULL
NULL   20     NULL
NULL   NULL   30
```

I would like to get

```
txt1   txt2   txt3
------------------
  10    20     30
```

Can someone help me get this result?

Comment: I think you'll need to build up the query from the values and execute the insert once for all 3 values or use an update ?

Comment: Build your parameters in the loop and execute after.

Comment: How can i build sir ?  i am very new to this !

Comment: Look at `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@txt1", txt.Text.Trim()));` being in your loop, controlled by the `if` for what parameter/textbox, then add the parameters accordingly.  So your connection set up will be outside the loop, building 1 `insert` and then the loop populating parameters.  Then your execute and close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if (txt.Name == "txt1")
{
    string str = "insert into sample1 (txt1) values ('" + txt.Text+"')";

    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
         conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@txt1", txt.Text.Trim()));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
}
```

to this

```
var textBoxNames = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 3)
    .Select(n => "txt" + n);

var textBoxes = Controls
    .OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(tb => textBoxNames.Contains(tb.Name));

var fields = textBoxNames
    .Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a}, {b}");

var pars = textBoxNames
    .Select(s => "@" + s)
    .Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a}, {b}");

string str = $"insert into sample1 ({fields}) values ({pars})";

if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
var parList = textBoxes
    .Select(tb => new SqlParameter("@" + tb.Name, tb.Text))
    .ToArray();
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parList);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

Comment: thnks for the reply will try and let you know

Comment: Yes, please. If your `if` block is inside a loop, as it seems so to me, then for the code I proposed you don't need it.

Comment: Hi, I have another question this is similar to the previous one, I am looking for the picture box images as well in the same way you provided the answer for textbox solution  if you can hemp me ! I will really appreciate it

Comment: You should ask a new question. Multiple questions are not allowed in one post. This is the rule at this site. Start a new post and community will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert values outside of your foreach loop.
First set values, then after foreach insert your records.

**Outside foreach loop write the code below:**

```cs
//This cant be in foreach loop

string str = "insert into sample1 (txt1, txt2, txt3) values (@txt1, @txt2, @txt3)";
if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
   conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@txt1", txt.Text.Trim()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@txt2", txt2.Text.Trim()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@txt3", txt3.Text.Trim()));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am using foreach

Comment: @user198455, There is no `foreach` in code you provided.

Comment: foreach (TextBox txt in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                { the insertion code comes here } and i have few more textboxes so just would like to insert only the created one  as metion about thanks

Comment: Even if I use this line       string str = "insert into sample1 (txt1) values (@txt1)"; it is the same result i get.

Comment: thnks for the reply will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

```
var textBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();

var columns = string.Join(", ", textBoxes.Select(tb => tb.Name));
var parameters = string.Join(", ", textBoxes.Select((_, i) => "@p" + i));

string sql = $"insert into sample1 ({columns}) values ({parameters})";

using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p" + i, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBoxes[i].Text;
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me something like this if it is picture boxes created dynamically instead of text boxes how can I do that ?

Comment: @user198455 - Clarify: in the case of PictureBox, do you need to save images in the database, not text? In any case, ask a new question (create a new topic).

Comment: sor for the late reply, Actually i need to put both text as well as picture box images yours post work very fine now i would like to do the same for the pictures same way as you showed the text I appreciate it your efforts for the reply as well as help

Comment: @user198455 - So, have you created a new topic?

Comment: Yer, sir going to to it, thnaks for thee reply

Comment: I have posted new question can you help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547236/how-to-insert-images-of-picture-box-which-is-created-by-for-loop