# How to insert images of picture box which is created by for loop?

Tags: c#, sql

If user enters 5 this loop creates 5 pictureboxes

```
        int.TryParse(text10.Text, out int a);

        for (i = 0; i < a; ++i)
        {
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.Name = ("pic" + (i + 1)).ToString();
            pb.Location = new Point(100, 150 + (850 * i));////this (850 * i)
            Size picsize = new Size(800, 800);
            pb.Size = picsize;
            pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pb.Click += clickonimage;
            pb.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            this.Controls.Add(pb);
        }
```

Here I have a click event for selecting image of each picture box

My question is...

**How can I insert those images of pictureBoxes into SQL SERVER at once?**

can anyone help ?

appreciate it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "at once"? You can insert them atomically in a transaction, but you still need N insert statements (where N is the number of pictures). How are you planning the respective table to look like?

Comment: I mean by single query

Comment: _"I mean by single query"_ - I don't think you can. At least not easily. _Maybe_ with some Stored Procedure Magic where you could pass a collection of pictures ... but I've never done something like that, tbh. And "under the hood" it would break up into N inserts, anyway. Just on the SQL Server, then.

Comment: Picture1 Picture2 Picture3 Picture4 Picture5  with repect of pictures get inserted into column name like Picture1 has pic1 and picture2 has pic2 and so on

Comment: That's an utterly bad idea: You lock yourself in to a certain number N of pictureboxes. If you need to persist any other number of pictures, you either waste space or cannot do it because it's too many. How would you identify the correct row to fetch (persisting them doesn't make much sense without being able to fetch them).

Comment: Actually this has been done with the textboxes and i have no idea about images

Comment: I did not notice you keep mentioning about N number of pictureboxes actually I have set the limit upto 8 only in my code

Comment: Well, Text is not as big as images, but still. Any change in your UI (adding or removing Textboxes) will trigger a table _schema_ change. That is really bad for maintainance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 5 picture boxes in your application and in your database table there are 5 columns to store image data then do as following demo code does

```
var pictureBoxNames = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 5)
    .Select(i => "pic" + i);
PictureBox[] pictureBoxes = Controls
    .OfType<PictureBox>()
    .Where(p => pictureBoxNames.Contains(p.Name))
    .ToArray();
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    DataSource = "MyServerAddress", //your server name
    InitialCatalog = "DataTable1"   //your data table name
};
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    var columns = string.Join(", ", pictureBoxNames.Select(s => $"[{s}]"));
    var pars = string.Join(", ", pictureBoxNames.Select(s => $"@{s}"));
    //Replace 'Table1' with your data table name here
    string commandText = $"INSERT INTO [Table1] ({columns}) VALUES ({pars})";
    using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection))
    {
        var imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
        Func<Image, object> ToByteArray = img
            => imageConverter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));

        var ps = pictureBoxes
            .Select(p => new SqlParameter($"@{p.Name}", ToByteArray(p.Image)))
            .ToArray();
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddRange(ps);
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi DotNet Developer, I appreciate your efforts this solution is awesome and perfect as expected I made few changes like connectionstringbuilder to sqlconnection and data type to varbinary(max) in sql and it is working very fine and in return I can say thanks.